# "Standard" vs "default" vs "basic" as a label for basic settings

Tags: mobile, terminology, default, novice-users

I am working on a mobile application which is targeted at regular people (not specialists, probably not much experience with software or desktops). The app provides basic / default / standard settings and user can adjust them and create favourite settings with their own label. The user has also a possibility to go back to the basic / default / standard settings.

A big and quick question is:
what should be the label of the button that allows to go back to these basic / dafault/ standard settings?

We have now 3 candidates:
-default
-standard
-basic

Which one should we choose? Which makes most sense for the "regular / non-technical" people?

Comment: Does changing the settings unlock more functionality that users pay for? It sounds like it's a free choice, almost like making a 'theme'

Comment: "create favourite settings with their own label"? my current guess is that you let the user pick some of settings that he wants to appear in the settings section and hide some others. Is there more to it?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can you run a simple label test with your customer base?

**Default** is often used when referring to an applications settings (i.e. choosing which program opens an image, which web browser to open by default). Things are reset to a default, or 'use default settings'.

It sounds like they aren't technical users, but if they've used iOS, windows, and setting up email (many tasks), the word default comes up rather frequently in relation to Settings.

NOTE: 'Default' does have one negative connotation; in the mortgage industry, a loan in default is not good at all!

In terms of [computer science](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/default?s=t):

> *Computers*. a value that a program or operating system assumes, or a course of action that a program or operating system will take, when the user or programmer specifies no overriding value or action.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**'Basic'** (and sometimes **standard**) is often used when referring to subscriptions and memberships; things that a customer does to or decrease a relationship with a vendor. It assumes increasing capacity of current features, or unlocking new features. I haven't seen instances of 'default' (If anyone has examples, please post) i.e.

- Basic
- Pro

'Basic' implies a limited set of features or functionality.

[image]

[image]

Is changing settings for your app unlocking more functionality and complexity? Or is it more like making a theme, where they create and name a subset of preferences?

If you can provide more context, I'll update my answer; I'm running on the info you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

## Basic

*Basic* is close to *Simple*, so it can sound like there is a scale from Simple to Advanced. Could your user create settings that are equally non-difficult, or even simpler? Then the word *basic* for your initial setup would not make sense anymore.

## Default

By your description, it sounds like the settings can be changed in a variety of ways and be saved under different labels. But the user is given the option to make them go back to as they were before they started fiddling with it. This is the proper use of *Default*.

## Standard

Close to both above cases, but also associated with price-tiers and best-practice. If you want to send the message about this setting that "this is all you need to get started" or "this is what most people use", then *Standard* is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Default seems to be often used for feature settings. This is true in websites, applications and games.

Standard and Basic seem to be used for subscription levels for services.

Comment: This is Mike M's answer in two lines. :D